# Invariant determinant in change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So I've seen the proof for why the determinant of a transformation $T$ is the same under a change of basis, but I must have some basic misconception about this since I can't figure out what's wrong with my logic in the following example.

Let $V$ be the space spanned by the functions $\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ and let $T(x)=f'$ from $V$ to $V$. Then under the basis $\cos(2x), \sin(2x)$, the transformation matrix is \begin{bmatrix} 0&2\\-2&0 \end{bmatrix} which has the determinant $4$.

But can't I technically say the basis is $\sin(2x), \cos(2x)$ (flipped), so the transformation matrix would be \begin{bmatrix} -2&0\\0&2 \end{bmatrix} giving a determinant of $-4$?

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip the basis on **both** the domain and range.

With the ordered basis $x \mapsto \sin (2x), x \mapsto \cos (2x)$, the matrix $T$ becomes
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have not correctly given the matrix representation with respect to the changed basis, $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$.  It is *not* a diagonal matrix as you showed, because not only the rows but also the columns must be swapped.